# Generate companion object for case class with methods (field = method)

Tags: scala, scala-macros, companion-object, scala-2.13

Generate companion object for case class with scala-macros

some code example that i tried, it works i can get list of tuple (name -> type) but how to generate the object in the same scope?

```
  import c.universe._
  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]

  val fields = tpe.decls.collectFirst {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isPrimaryConstructor => m
  } .get
    .paramLists
    .head

  val extractParams = fields.map { field =>
    val name = field.asTerm.name
    val fieldName = name.decodedName.toString
    val NullaryMethodType(fieldType) = tpe.decl(name).typeSignature

    c.Expr[List[(String, String)]](
      q"""
       ($fieldName, ${fieldType.toString})
      """
    )
```

Is it possible to annotate some case class and the generated companion make visible in the same scope?

```scala
// test case: defined a class with some fields
@GenerateCompanionWithFields
case class SomeCaseClass(i: Int, b: Byte, c: Char)
```

goal:

```scala
SomeCaseClass.i() // returns Int 
SomeCaseClass.b() // returns Byte
SomeCaseClass.c() // returns Char
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be intended for [def macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html). But if you want to generate companion you should use [macro annotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

object Macros {
  @compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise")
  class GenerateCompanionWithFields extends StaticAnnotation {
    def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro Macro.impl
  }

  object Macro {
    def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
      import c.universe._
      annottees match {
        case (cls @ q"$_ class $tpname[..$_] $_(...$paramss) extends { ..$_ } with ..$_ { $_ => ..$_ }") :: Nil =>

          val newMethods = paramss.flatten.map {
            case q"$_ val $tname: $tpt = $_" =>
              q"def $tname(): String = ${tpt.toString}"
          }

          q"""
             $cls

             object ${tpname.toTermName} {
               ..$newMethods
             }
           """
      }
    }
  }
}

import Macros._

object App {
  @GenerateCompanionWithFields
  case class SomeCaseClass(i: Int, b: Byte, c: Char)
}

//Warning:scalac: {
//  case class SomeCaseClass extends scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val i: Int = _;
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val b: Byte = _;
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val c: Char = _;
//    def <init>(i: Int, b: Byte, c: Char) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  object SomeCaseClass extends scala.AnyRef {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    def i(): String = "Int";
//    def b(): String = "Byte";
//    def c(): String = "Char"
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

[automatically generate case object for case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048310/automatically-generate-case-object-for-case-class/)

Comment: Thank you! But i have a little problem this code does not compile ${tpname.toTermName} - cannot resolve the "toTermName"

my project structure:

project ---- core ---- macros

Comment: @Code_VM Are you sure? Do you use IntelliJ? For me in Scala 2.13.0 IntelliJ shows `toTermName` in red color but everything compiles. Try `sbt compile`. Did you add "scala-reflect" library dependency? Your project structure looks ok. Normally you have subproject for macros ("macros") and subproject where you use macros ("core").

Comment: @Code_VM You can try to replace `tpname.toTermName` with `TermName(tpname.toString)`.

Comment: yes i have exactly the same problem toTermName in red color, and yes i use IntelliJ.

of course macro and core subprojects are declared as you described

Comment: @Code_VM It's ok when IntelliJ highlights Scala code sometimes in red (dependent types, macros etc.). Important is whether the code compiles.

Comment: finally got time to finish the job. it works, thanks a lot!