# Case class and companion object sharing namespace and implementation?

Tags: scala, class, boilerplate, companion-object

So, It is not a global problem. But... its like a DRY problem.
Lets introduce it.
If I have a trait with some abstract member

```
trait WithSomeValue {
val someValue: Int
}
```

and some structure with case classes and their companions both inherited from this trait,
if I have to make some static thing like a value and save it in Static(companion), like this:

```
object Foo extends WithSomeValue {
override val someValue: Int = 1
}
```

I need to assign it while implement trait in case class too

```
case class Foo(val x: Int) extends WithSomeValue {
override val someValue: Int = Foo.somevalue// I don`t like to write this! I feel myself DRY and tired ;)
}
```

What can I do? Can I do something elegant not to write this assignment again and again? To write it in one place only?

I need to have available static members in static context
and I have to get an hierarchy - trait->case class both? but I don`t want to write DRY code. I hope some trick exists, to avoid code duplication.

Comment: It is kind of a weird design that `someValue` is accessible both as an instance member as well as a _"static"_ member of the same type. - What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can override the member in a common parent of the case class and its companion object

```
trait WithSomeValue {
  val someValue: Int
}

trait WithSomeValueImpl extends WithSomeValue {
  override val someValue: Int = 1
}

object Foo extends WithSomeValueImpl
case class Foo(x: Int) extends WithSomeValueImpl

Foo.someValue     // 1
Foo(42).someValue // 1
```

---

> I don't need one static value for all hierarchy but one value per object companion

What about

```
trait WithSomeValue {
  val someValue: Int
}

trait FooLike extends WithSomeValue {
  override val someValue: Int = 1
}

object Foo extends FooLike
case class Foo(x: Int) extends FooLike

trait BarLike extends WithSomeValue {
  override val someValue: Int = 2
}

object Bar extends BarLike
case class Bar(x: Int) extends BarLike
```

?

---

Actually, this is not a code duplication because a case class and its companion object are absolutely different classes

[Class companion object vs. case class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286750/class-companion-object-vs-case-class-itself/)

`someValue` can be implemented in them absolutely differently.

Anyway you can use the following [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) (see sbt settings below). It generates the member in the companion object copying the member from a class. If the companion object doesn't exist the annotation creates it.

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
class companionSomeValue extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro CompanionSomeValueMacros.macroTransformImpl
}

object CompanionSomeValueMacros {
  def macroTransformImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    def modify(cls: ClassDef, obj: ModuleDef): Tree = (cls, obj) match {
      case (
        q"$_ class $_[..$_] $_(...$_) extends { ..$_ } with ..$_ { $_ => ..$stats }",
        q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }"
      ) =>
        val someValue = stats.collectFirst {
          case t@q"$_ val someValue: $_ = $_" => t
        }.get

        q"""
          $cls

          $mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
            ..$body
            $someValue
          }
        """
    }

    annottees match {
      case (cls: ClassDef) :: (obj: ModuleDef) :: Nil => modify(cls, obj)
      case (cls: ClassDef) :: Nil => modify(cls, q"object ${cls.name.toTermName} extends WithSomeValue")
    }
  }
}
```

```
// in a different subproject

trait WithSomeValue {
  val someValue: Int
}

@companionSomeValue
case class Foo(x: Int) extends WithSomeValue {
  override val someValue: Int = 1
}
object Foo extends WithSomeValue

@companionSomeValue
case class Bar(x: Int) extends WithSomeValue {
  override val someValue: Int = 2
}

Foo.someValue     // 1
Foo(42).someValue // 1
Bar.someValue     // 2
Bar(42).someValue // 2

//scalac: {
//  case class Foo extends WithSomeValue with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val x: Int = _;
//    def <init>(x: Int) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue: Int = 1
//  };
//  object Foo extends WithSomeValue {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue: Int = 1
//  };
//  ()
//}

//scalac: {
//  case class Bar extends WithSomeValue with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val x: Int = _;
//    def <init>(x: Int) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue: Int = 2
//  };
//  object Bar extends WithSomeValue {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue: Int = 2
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

---

Slightly different implementation. The annotation generates the member in a class delegating to the member of the companion object.

```
@compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
class someValueFromCompanion extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro SomeValueFromCompanionMacros.macroTransformImpl
}

object SomeValueFromCompanionMacros {
  def macroTransformImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    def modifyClass(cls: ClassDef): ClassDef = cls match {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" =>
        q"""
          $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
            ..$stats
            override val someValue = ${tpname.toTermName}.someValue
          }
        """
    }

    def modify(cls: ClassDef, obj: ModuleDef): Tree = q"..${Seq(modifyClass(cls), obj)}"

    annottees match {
      case (cls: ClassDef) :: (obj: ModuleDef) :: Nil => modify(cls, obj)
    }
  }
}
```

```
@someValueFromCompanion
case class Foo(x: Int) extends WithSomeValue
object Foo extends WithSomeValue {
  override val someValue: Int = 1
}

@someValueFromCompanion
case class Bar(x: Int) extends WithSomeValue
object Bar extends WithSomeValue {
  override val someValue: Int = 2
}

//scalac: {
//  case class Foo extends WithSomeValue with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val x: Int = _;
//    def <init>(x: Int) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue = Foo.someValue
//  };
//  object Foo extends WithSomeValue {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue: Int = 1
//  };
//  ()
//}

//scalac: {
//  case class Bar extends WithSomeValue with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val x: Int = _;
//    def <init>(x: Int) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue = Bar.someValue
//  };
//  object Bar extends WithSomeValue {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override val someValue: Int = 2
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

[Auto-Generate Companion Object for Case Class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74497076/auto-generate-companion-object-for-case-class-in-scala) (sbt settings for macro annotations)

[automatically generate case object for case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048310/automatically-generate-case-object-for-case-class/)

[Generate companion object for case class with methods (field = method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740226/generate-companion-object-for-case-class-with-methods-field-method)

Comment: I don't need one static value for all hierarchy but one value per object companion. (For example class Bar, with someValue = 2)

Comment: interesting solution, but I have to use case classes only, not traits =/